# Strange NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, adapter, fragment

I'm trying to pass a string value from my listview adapter to my fragment using the following code but I get a null pointer exception. Breaking it down told me that the error is in calling the method, but I don't see anything wrong

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
       String text =  myList.get(position);
       resetArrbg();
       arrBgcolor[position] = true;
       DevFragment def = new DevFragment();
       def.clicked(text);
 }
```

The error is definitely in the last two lines, because if I replace them with a Toast using the text variable, it works
The corresponding method in the fragment is

```
public void clicked(String arg1)
{    
      globalString == arg1;
}
```

Comment: plz also add logcat results if you are getting NullPointer Exception instead of showing only code

Comment: So put a breakpoint on `DevFragment def = new DevFragment()` and step through.  What's null?

Answer (score 5):

```
 globalString == arg1;
```

you want to assing the String not compare its address

```
 globalString = arg1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
globalString == arg1;
```

In above lines you are comparing String objects instead of assigning it. I think you should replace this by-

```
globalString = arg1;
```